# Spring Security OAuth2 How to generate temporary token for file download

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-rest

In my app I'm using Spring Security Authorization server and Spring Security Resource server. Everything works fine, user logs in, gets issued access_token and can use it to access the API.

Now I need to allow the user to download a file from URL (think `<button onClick="window.open(/files/1/download")>`.

My idea is to create new endpoint which will issue a temporary access_token to the user and the user then can add it as part of URL `windows.open('/files/1/download?access_token=<temp-token>')`

I have tried using `TokenEndpoint` and `AuthorizationServerTokenServices` but those will not allow me to control parameters of the new token.

What's the correct way to generate the token?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a service which creates and validates JWT?

```
@Service
public class TokenProvider {

    public String createToken(User user) {

        Date now = new Date();
        Date expiryDate = new Date(now.getTime() + 5000); // Token will expire in 5 seconds

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(Long.toString(user.getId()))
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(expiryDate)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, "YOUR-SECRET-KEY")
                .compact();
    }
    
    public Long getUserIdFromToken(String token) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey("YOUR-SECRET-KEY")
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();

        return Long.parseLong(claims.getSubject());
    }
    
    public boolean validateToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("YOUR-SECRET-KEY").parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException ex) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT signature");
        } catch (MalformedJwtException ex) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token");
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
            logger.error("Expired JWT token");
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException ex) {
            logger.error("Unsupported JWT token");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty.");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```